# Css3 hyperlink button dysplayed outside of parent div and going HUGE

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a webpage with with some hyperlink buttons next to some text. I coded it the other day and it was just fine. It is giving me nuts.

However, today when I went back to it the button was bumping out of its div, and had a dimension at least five times the supposed one.

Being unable to locate the piece of css where the problem resides, I have copied the relevant HTML area and uploaded the resulting page at url http://prova.webuda.com/biglietti.html.

The problematic element is the huge green button on the right of the page.

If all was working properly the page should display two lines of 50px height of with match information, now one line is taking up the whole screenview ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Coming back as `width: 14em;`. Do you have that anywhere in your 8 `css` docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your .buttonDiv class has the folowing settings:

```
width: 15px;
max-width: 15px;
float: right;
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

that is doing most of what you describe.. it doesnt look perfect but removing those results in this:

[image]

Comment: Ok thakns. Your suggestion put me on the right track! You're tha man!